# Trouble changing SSH port

Tags: centos, ssh, port

I'm running a CENTOS web server with WHM and CSF firewall. I'm trying to change SSH from the default port. I've opened up the port in CSF and modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` uncommenting the port line and changing it to the port I want it to be on. I've then restarted SSH using WHM and command line and it restarts. However when it restarts it's still using the default port of 22. What am I doing wrong?

Settings from sshd_config file:

```
# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
Port 2222
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
Host *
```

Then here's the copy from my console so you can see what I ran:

```
root@vps1 [~]# cd /etc/ssh
root@vps1 [/etc/ssh]# vi ssh_config
root@vps1 [/etc/ssh]# /etc/init.d/sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
root@vps1 [/etc/ssh]#
```

I then ran `netstat -tuplen` to check the port it was running on:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          36862521   8315/sshd
```

Still running on port 22.

Comment: What you're doing sounds right, so I suspect the devil is in the details.  Could you **show** us what you've done, instead of **telling** us?  Cutting-and-pasting bits of the relevant files and terminal sessions into your question is a good way to do that.

Comment: I only modified `sshd_config`, so I've copied the settings from there. As you can see I've only edited the port in there. I've copied the commands I ran in the terminal and as you can see it all went fine. But as you can see from `netstat` it's still on the wrong port. I've also tested it as I'm using PuTTY to make these changes. I'm still connected on port 22 and if I try the new port I can't connect.

Comment: OK, thanks.  That's weird.  Could you perhaps do a `service sshd stop`, then `/usr/sbin/sshd -d`, and paste the debug output in here?  Don't forget to do a `service sshd` start after you give the debugged one a CTRL-C, otherwise you may shut yourself out the box!

Comment: From what you just added, you edited `ssh_config` not `sshd_config`. You need to edit `sshd_config`

Comment: I can't as I'm connected via SSH to do this.

Comment: Yes, you can; `service sshd stop` doesn't disconnect the current session.  But in any case, I think faker may have put his finger on it - can you confirm positively which file you've edited?  `grep -i port /etc/ssh/sshd_config` would probably be helpful.

Comment: That's done it, I was editing the wrong file. Thank you.

Comment: Yaay faker, +1 from me.  Styphon, your question serves as a **perfect** example of why show-not-tell is a good rule!  You might want to take that lesson away with you for future questions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have in your question is not a `sshd_config` that is a `ssh_config`.
You need to edit `sshd_config` instead and restart `sshd` afterwards.

`ssh_config` is the client configuration and has no effect on daemon settings.